# Getting a CLI error when trying to compile

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, php, cli

I am getting this error on terminal:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Cli' not found in /opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs/bin/magento on line 31
```

when trying to run these commands:

```
sudo php bin/magento setup:upgrade
sudo php bin/magento setup:di:compile
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: you should run those commands inside your Magento root directory.

Comment: That's where I am running them.

Comment: did it happen during the upgrade or compile?

Comment: Both. Anytime I run a command that starts with: sudo php bin/magento

Comment: I see. can you try to run `composer update` first then after, try if commands are working

Comment: or upload it directly to your magento root dir. https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.3-develop/composer.lock

Comment: please mark as right if it solves your query.

Answer (score 1):

Enter your php path while running bin/magento commands.

```
sudo /opt/lampp/bin/php bin/magento setup:upgrade
sudo /opt/lampp/bin/php bin/magento setup:di:compile
```